# Add Custom Link Under Existing Categories

Tags: category, magento2.2.2, topmenu

I would like to add some links under a specific categories, **not subcategories** !

Normally you would create a subcategory under a category and so on but, I need to add some filter link which in turn it will look like it's subcategory.E.G

[image]

TEST-CATEGORY is a Category created from admin backend but MY CUSTOM LINK 1 and MY CUSTOM LINK 2 are **not**

Anyone have any Idea how to intercept that an append some link to it ?

Appreciate!

Comment: Is your custom links manageable from Admin Panel? or it just static?

Comment: @ Abhishek Panchal  Well that is a different story but it can be from and array that come from som backend module or just a static block or phtml I open to any option to be honest.

Comment: and you want it for each Main category like Test-Category, Test-category-1 and test-category-2?

Comment: @ Abhishek Panchal No I only need to apply custom link under one category only.